# Matrices and linear maps End($V$) of infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am struggling to understand the following concept required to solve a task that I found in my Algebra book.

The task: Let $V$ be (a possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space and $A$ an endomorphism. Furthermore let $\sigma(A)$ be the set of Eigenvalues of $A$ (analogously for the endomorphism $B$). Show that $\sigma(AB)\setminus\{0\}=\sigma(BA)\setminus\{0\}$.

My initial instinct was to represent $A$ and $B$ as $n\times n$ matrices and do some brute-force calculation and show that the characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$ are similar. However, I am having second doubts regarding the representation of $A$ and $B$ as $n\times n$ matrices as I cannot represent the basis of $V$ in only $n$ variables (it might be infinite-dimensional).

This concern left me in doubt whether I should solve it with matrices at all or somehow express the eigenvalues through $(A\circ B)(v)=\lambda v$. Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea or motivation from the finite dimensional case is that $AB$ and $BA$ are "almost similar." Like, we have $B(AB)B^{-1} = BA$ except $B$ might not be invertible. So you have to work around the non-invertibility by assuming you're not in $\ker B$ or something like that.

So suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ corresponding to a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then what we would like to do is define a vector $w$ such that $B^{-1}w = v \iff w = Bv$ and then we have

$$BAw = B(AB)B^{-1}w = B(AB)v = B(\lambda v) = \lambda Bv = \lambda w.$$

Now this works fine if $B$ is invertible. If $B$ is not invertible then all we need to do to fix this is to cut out the second expression:

$$BAw = B(AB)v = B(\lambda v) = \lambda Bv = \lambda w.$$

Therefore $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ corresponding to the non-zero (!!) eigenvector $w = Bv$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mind elaborating on 1) Why $w$ cannot be zero. 2) Why you can assume that $\lambda\neq 0$. Consider the following: Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ s.t. $AB(v)=0$. Therefore $B(v)\in\ker A$. Now let $w=B(v)$ and therefore $BA(w)=BAB(v)=B(0)=0$ so that $\lambda=0$ is a common eigenvalue of $AB$ and $BA$.

Comment: @EdwardTeach I take $\lambda \neq 0$ because we're trying to show $\sigma(AB)\setminus\{0\}=\sigma(BA)\setminus\{0\}$. We know that $Bv \neq 0$ because $ABv \neq 0$.

Comment: Right, because $v\neq 0$. As a side question: Why doesn't $\sigma(AB)=\sigma(BA)$ hold for infinite-dimensional spaces? However, I will mark your answer as the solution and would like to thank you for your help!

Comment: @EdwardTeach Take $V$ to be the space of infinite sequences $(a_0,a_1,\dots)$ and let $A$ shift the sequence to the left (deleting $a_0$) and $B$ shift the sequence to the right. Then $AB$ is the identity and $BA$ has a non-trivial kernel.